# Generar exe con Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Estoy intentando generar un exe en de un solo archivo con Pyinstaller para crear archivos docx pero al ejecutar el exe me da un fallo que no ha incluido la librería docx y he visto que con los hook que se puede solucionar pero sigue dándome error

example.py

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.save("demo.docx")
```

hook.py

```
document.add_heading("Example")
```

CMD

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. --onefile example.py
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docx import Document
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
[7844] Failed to execute script example
```

Comment: prueba usando: `pyintaller -hidden-import=docx ...`

Answer (score 0):

¿Te funciona si utilizas *pyinstaller* sin el argumento *--onefile*?

En ese caso puedes empaquetar tu programa con:

```
pyinstaller example.py
```

Se habrá creado un directorio *dist/example* que contiene tu programa empaquetado.

Ahora puedes utilizar [Bat to Exe Converter](https://zn.amorgan.xyz/17SWVnHoujG92yYGSZvCzPgZEpGVfRF8wi) para convertir tu programa en *portable*. Para ello crea un archivo **example.bat** y escribe lo siguiente:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD example
example.exe
```

Desde *Bat to Exe Converter* ve al menú *Archivo - Abrir* y selecciona tu *example.bat*. A la derecha tienes una pestaña *embed* donde puedes arrastrar y soltar la carpeta que contiene tu programa (example). Haz click en el botón *Convertir* y listo.

*Bat to Exe Converter* además te permite poner un icono a tu programa, ocultar la consola y muchas mas opciones. Es de gran ayuda cuando *pyinstaller* parece empeñarse en no funcionar del todo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

yo use lo siguiente

1. pip install pyinstaller ( esto instalara el programa)
2. Luego te posicionas en la ruta del archivo .py y haces:
3. `pyinstaller --onefile archivo.py`
   Esta ultima línea creara una carpeta dist. dentro de esta estara el .exe .
4. Despues haz un acceso directo de este y listo.